# How to localize Python's argparse module, without patching it?

Tags: python, localization, argparse

A localized command line application looks strange when some part of the messages are in the user language and some other parts, in English.

I don't know if I messed up anything when I installed Python 3 from source, it seems there are no `*.mo` files, so `argparse` (among the whole) is not localization aware.

The API does not seems to offer a way to localize, neither. Or did I missed it?

I could patch `argparse.py`, but I won't, as I want it to be portable, and I'm not OK with suggesting users to patch their Python installation.

**Question** in fewer words: how to localize `argpase` without patching Python standard library?

**Related question**: is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default `argparse` uses the `gettext` module to translate the messages so you can easily translate them if you want to.

To generate the `*.pot` files (which you can convert to `*.mo` files after translation) you can use the `pygettext` program which is available in the built-in `gettext` module in python.

Usage:

```
python pygettext.py argparse.py
```

This will generate a `messages.pot` which you can translate, after that just generate the `.mo` (many ways to do this, just google).

For more info about `pygettext` see the Python manual about the subject: [*Internationalizing your programs and modules*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gettext.html#internationalizing-your-programs-and-modules).

Comment: I missed the `_(` in `argparse.py`, thanks for the notice. I can generate a POT file, indeed, and then concatenate it to the package's one, using `msgcat`: i.e., something like `msgcat --to-code=UTF-8 --output=all-messages.pot package-messages.pot argparse.pot`. I did not knew about `pygettext`; I tested it, and will go on with `xgettext`, as I don't like all the escape sequences it outputs with all characters beyond ASCII, like with ` “ ” ` (it's not readable in, say, Virtaal).

Comment: Hi, I couldn't find the way to do this as you described, I am writing a small program and need (not really but ideal) to translate the "usage:" string in help to spanish. The way you described would need to append the .po to something, how can this be portable? I don't want the user to have to do something to get this little string translated. Thanks!