# Translate argparse's internal strings

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

How can I translate Python's argparse module strings?

For example, when you display the help, it says `"usage: "`, string that is translatable but I don't know how to do it in my program.

This is the source code part of `argparse.py`:

```
def _format_usage(self, usage, actions, groups, prefix):
        if prefix is None:
            prefix = _('usage: ')
```

I couldn't trace the way to set this prefix, I think this is internal.

I don't want to have to append a .mo file to somewhere in the system. Ideally the translation should live in my program directory, or better in the source code.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running the following:

```
import argparse

class MyHelpFormatter(argparse.HelpFormatter):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyHelpFormatter, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def _format_usage(self, usage, actions, groups, prefix):
        return super(MyHelpFormatter, self)._format_usage(
            usage, actions, groups, prefix if prefix else "bla: ")

class MyArgumentParser(argparse.ArgumentParser):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['formatter_class']=MyHelpFormatter
        super(MyArgumentParser, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)


p = MyArgumentParser(description='Foo')
p.add_argument('foo', type=str)
print p.parse_args()
```

prints

```
python myargparse.py  --help
bla: myargparse.py [-h] foo

Foo

positional arguments:
  foo

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
```

`_('usage: ')` references [`gettext`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/gettext.html). In `argparse.py`, at the top, you have:

```
from gettext import gettext as _
```

You can muck around with `gettext` a bit.

Given a `.po` file:

```
msgid "usage: "
msgstr "foobar: "
```

You can convert it to a `.mo` file (for example [here](http://po2mo.net/)).

Afterwards (where `./foo/LC_MESSAGES/messages.mo` is the result of compiling the `.po`):

```
~/Desktop> find . -name *mo
./foo/LC_MESSAGES/messages.mo
~/Desktop> cat myargparse2.py
import argparse
import gettext
gettext.bindtextdomain(gettext.textdomain(), '.')
p = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Foo')
p.add_argument('foo', type=str)
print p.parse_args()
~/Desktop> LANGUAGE=foo python myargparse2.py
foobar: myargparse2.py [-h] foo
myargparse2.py: error: too few arguments
```

Use your desired languages instead of `foo`.

Comment: Many thanks. I don't have any problem to mess with gettext, but the only solution I saw was a guy talking about "appending" the translation file to another one (I didn't understand much). If I can have the translation file inside my program directory, say "/home/me/project/translations" it is not a problem, but if I have to modify an existing Python's .mo file then I don't want to do it. Maybe you can put some light on it. I guess `argparse` has a `domain` or something like that where it looks for its translations

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28730641/how-to-localize-pythons-argparse-module-without-patching-it

Comment: I added a proof of concept for adding a simple `.mo` file. I've never touched `gettext` before, so not sure if it's the right approach, but it seems to work.

Comment: Hey I tested your approach and it works. gettext recommends using the Class API, so I tried, but can't get it to work. Do you have a clue? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35347168/python-3-gettext-not-working-for-argparse

Answer (score 1):

Based on Vlad's answer, I made it shorter:

```
class CustomHelpFormatter(argparse.HelpFormatter):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CustomHelpFormatter, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def _format_usage(self, usage, actions, groups, prefix):
        return super(CustomHelpFormatter, self)._format_usage(
            usage, actions, groups, prefix if prefix else "Uso: ")


if __name__ == "__main__":

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog="jcheq.py",
                                     usage="%(prog)s [opciones] [paths...]\nThe paths are optional; if not given . is "
                                           "used.",
                                     add_help=False,
                                     formatter_class=CustomHelpFormatter)
```